# Matlab - derivative of a function expression

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I have the following non-linear equation

[image]

Where A1, B1, C1, D1, E1, A2, B2, C2, D2, E2 are some constants. However, Z is some function of eta(z = z(eta)).

Is it possible, in Matlab, to get an expression for the (first and second)derivative of the above equation with respect to eta i.e dz/d-eta and d^2z/d-eta^2?

I have tried `diff(aboveexpression,eta)` . But this treats `z` as constant.

How do I tackle this?

Comment: Well, you can not get teh derivative of `z` without defining `z` I guess

Comment: Have you checked out symbolic functions and variables already?
 That is, [symfun](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/symfun.html) or  [symbolic differentiation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/diff.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible (and it is possible without determining the analytical expression for `z`). You can use the [inverse function differentiation rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_functions_and_differentiation):

[image]

```
syms A1 B1 C1 D1 E1 A2 B2 C2 D2 E2 z
F= A1*atan(B1*asinh(C1*z-D1)+E1)+A2*atan(B2*asinh(C2*z-D2)+E2);
dz= 1/diff(F,z) % the first derivative
```

Now the second derivative. We need to differentiate the resulting expression `dz`, where `z` is a function of `eta`. We can use the fact that

[image]

```
d2z= diff(dz,z)*dz  % the second derivative
```

Comment: I am little confused by the expression you obtained for the second derivative. What happened to the second term($\frac{\partial z'}{\partial \eta}$) Can you please explain that?

Comment: The term $\frac{\partial z'}{\partial \eta}$ is equal to `0` because `z'` that we obtained does not depend (explicitly) on `eta`, it depends only on `z(eta)`.